# How do I test salesforce web applications for browser stability?

Tags: browser, web-applications, salesforce, stress-testing, stability

The problem occurs in salesforce web applications.

Operations like changing or updating a field sometimes don't function on the clients' browsers but work on my browser.

Customers try to use the browser to execute a function (such as revising a budget), but the browser freezes and won't let them continue.